# Oracle SQL: How to fetch only style tag attributes from column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to fetch only style tag attributes from a column i.e., style tag between double quotes ("). Style= can be anywhere in the column.
Below is the sample data:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                          STYLE_ATTR                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| style="width:440px; " aria-label="Test Aria Label"           |
| data-method="getTestData" style="margin-left: 10px"          |
| id="DEMO" style="float: left; " aria-label="Test Aria Label" |
| style="font-size: 100% ; "                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Expected: Output:

```
+-------------------+
|    STYLE_ATTR     |
+-------------------+
| width:440px;      |
| margin-left: 10px |
| float: left;      |
| font-size: 100% ; |
+-------------------+
```

Tried below code:

```
select SUBSTR(style_attr, INSTR(style_attr, 'style=')+6) AS style_attr from test_table
```

With this I am getting double quotes also in the output. Need help on how to get only style tags without double quotes.

Thanks,
Richa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy with what you got but want to get rid of double quotes, so replace them with an empty string:

```
select REPLACE(SUBSTR(style_attr, INSTR(style_attr, 'style=')+6), '"', '') AS style_attr 
from test_table
```

Comment: thank you for quick response. I appreciate. Solution worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure REGEXP solution:

```
-- test data written as cte for example
WITH test_table(style_attr) as
(
SELECT 'style="width:440px; " aria-label="Test Aria Label" data-method="getTestData" style="margin-left: 10px" id="DEMO" 
style="float: left; " aria-label="Test Aria Label" style="font-size: 100% ; "' FROM DUAL 
)
-- use regexp_substr to extract only the style="... attributes and 
-- CONNECT BY LEVEL to get one row per occurence
, test_table_only_style_attr(val) as
(
SELECT 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(style_attr,'(style="[^"]+")',1,level,'i') from test_table
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(style_attr,'(style="[^"]+")',1,level,'i') IS NOT NULL
)
-- use backreference to get the value between the double quotes
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(val,'(style=")([^"]+)(")','\2') AS result from test_table_only_style_attr;

width:440px; 
margin-left: 10px
float: left; 
font-size: 100% ;
```

Note that REGEXP is pretty costly so if you are doing this on a large dataset, @Littlefoot's answer will be more performant.

Comment: thank you for providing different perspective for the question. I totally forgot that I can use regexp. This solution gave me result like this: width:440px;  aria-label="Test Aria Label" for first row and similar results with every other row

Comment: Strange, when I run that script I get the results that I posted. here too: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=551c2f09c0416749dd0db5a0c37fbc33 Are you doing exactly the same ?

Comment: Sorry that I did not mention this earlier. If I run your query the way it is, it works perfect. If I use the regexp code in my select statement, it is not working. It shows the result as I posted in previous comment. Here's the query I am using:
select style_attr, REGEXP_REPLACE(style_attr,'(style=")([^"]+)(")','\2') as result from test_table

Comment: I copied the test data from your question and used that to test my response. There must be a difference between your data and what is posted here on stack overflow. Unless I know what that difference is I can't help you.